# Taylor series approximation using for a pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, taylor-expansion

I have an question which links Taylor series to expectation and variance, but I'm really not sure what it's asking me to do.

X is exponential with rate 1.

The question asks me to use a three term Taylor series approximation for $\psi(X)=x^{-1\over 2}$ to approximate $\pi$ by evaluating $E[\psi(X)]$. And then use a two term Taylor's series approximation to approximate $Var(\psi(X))$. I'm really not certain how these steps link and how I would do the approximations.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You will have been given the distribution of $X$.

Comment: ? I've been given $\psi(X)=x^{-1\over 2}$, is that not enough?

Comment: The equation of the comment does not make sense, we have $X$ on one side and $x$ on he other. The expectation of $\psi(X)$ depends on the distribution of the random variable $X$. Without knowing the distribution of $X$, we cannot solve the problem. I am confident that the original problem has not been fully quoted.

Comment: I've edited it now and added X=exp(1). Hopefully it makes more sense now. Sorry about that.